# validation max_length, min_length in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am getting an error when trying to set custom validation messages in `CodeIgniter` for the `min_length` and `max_length` validation constraints.

These are my validation rules:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[10]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]';
```

These are my custom validation message:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length[3]', '%s: the minimum of characters is three');
$this->form_validation->set_message('max_length[20]', '%s:the maximum of characters is 20');
```

In my example we have two fields, but I have many fields with different minimum and maximum length values. They all have a specific constraint validations. This messages doesn't work. The message appears by default.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11):

### Just add another `%s` to get the length value..

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', '%s: the minimum of characters is %s');
```

You will give the size only if you use `%s` **second time**. first time it will give field name you specified..

Answer (score 10):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]';
```

is missing a closing bracket -- `)`:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]');
```

**Update**
Perhaps using a [callback](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) function would be better? E.g.:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|xss_clean|callback__check_length[6,10]');


/**
 * Callback function. Checks if the length of the user's input
 * conforms to minimum and maximum character length requirements
 *
 * @param  string
 * @param  int
 * @param  int
 * @return bool
 */
function _check_length($input, $min, $max)
{
    $length = strlen($input);

    if ($length <= $max && $length >= $min)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    elseif ($length < $min)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_length', 'Minimum number of characters is ' . $min);
        return FALSE;        
    }
    elseif ($length > $max)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_length', 'Maximum number of characters is ' . $max);
        return FALSE;        
    }
}
```

Comment: In my source code it's ok.  I forgot to put the closing bracked when I did my post. My doubt continue.  Thanks for your correction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll review your answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When using `set_message`, you can't specify the lengths (both min and max) the way that you have done. You can either set a general message for `min_length` and `max_length` like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'The value you have entered for %s is too short');
$this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'The value you have entered for %s is too long');
```

Otherwise, you will have to utilise `CodeIgniter`'s callback feature and set up a custom validation function which would look something like this (for the minimum length!!).

```
public function custom_min_length($str, $val) {
    if (preg_match("/[^0-9]/", $val)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
        if(mb_strlen($str) < $val) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('custom_min_length', '%s: The Minimum Number Of Characters Is ' . $val);
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    if(strlen($str) < $val) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('custom_min_length', '%s: The Minimum Number Of Characters Is ' . $val);
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

You would set your validation rule like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_custom_min_length[6]|required|xss_clean');
```

Notice the `callback_` prefix on the `custom_min_length` rule. This replaces, and is used instead of the usual `min_length` CI function.

Hope that helps...I'll leave you figure out how to do the `custom_max_length` function :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll review your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show your own validation message, do something like that:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('min_length','YOUR MESSAGE');
```

without the branches: [num]

Greetings